# SQLite3 JOIN 4 tables to form a query

Tags: join, sqlite

I am not that versed at some advanced SQL but need to create a SELECT query using JOINS that links data across 4 tables. ( using * as the field selector for all tables)

```
Table 1 (Project Tasks) (Fields: parent_project_id, ...)
Table 2 (Parent Project Details) (Fields: id [KEY], dept_id, ...)
Table 3 (Department) (Fields: id [KEY], manager_id, ...)
Table 4 (Resources) (Fields: employee_id [KEY], email, ...) 

parent_project_id(Table 1) maps to id(Table 2)
dept_id(Table 2) maps to id(Table 3)
manager_id(Table 3) maps to employee_id(Table 4)
```

I would like to be able to return a list of Project Task details that include the Parent Project details, Department details, and Manager's details on each line.

Would someone be able to help me with the SQL statement required to do this?

Answer (score 0):

*Every* SQL tutorial explains how to do joins.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.parent_project_id = table2.id
JOIN table3 ON table2.dept_id = table3.id
JOIN table4 ON table3.manager_id = table4.employee_id
```